# Entity Framework Query filters implementation for best perfomance

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, entity-framework-4

As the title says, I´m using entity framework 4.0 for a financial application. I have a winform where I list all the cheques (checks) I have. But in that form, the user can specify some filters.

[image]

If the user does not apply any filter, I just can make the query like this:

```
lista_cheques = db.Cheque.Include("Operacion").Include("Cliente").ToList();
datagridview.Datasource = lista_cheques;
```

That is simple. But when it applies filters, the problem gets bigger.

As you see, the user can use filter to see cheques (checks) of a specific client, dates, bank, CUIT number, check state, etc.

Now, my question is related to performance in the queries.

I was thinking on doing the filters separeted, like this:

```
lista_cheques = db.Cheque.Include("Operacion").Include("Cliente").Where(x => x.fecha_deposito == fecha).ToList();
lista_cheques = lista_cheques.Where(x => x.banco.id_banco = banco).ToList();
lista_cheques = lista_cheques.Where(x => x.Operacion.Cliente.id_cliente = id_cliente).ToList();
```

Translation:
fecha is date
Operacion is a group of checks
Cliente is client.

In this way, I´m doing a query, then, a query from that query result, then a new query from that new result and that goes on.

I think this way might have a big performance issues. I know that SQL server optimize queries. So, if I´m doing fragmented queries, the optimizer is not working properly.

The other way I thought about but it´s very tedious, is to create one big query to handle every possible filter selection.

For example, the other example would be like this:

```
lista_cheques = db.Cheque.Include("Operacion").Include("Cliente").Where(x => x.fecha_deposito == fecha && x.banco.id_banco = banco && x.Operacion.Cliente.id_cliente = id_cliente).ToList();
```

The big problem is that I will need lots of combinations to be able to handle all the filter posibilities.

Ok guys, now, will I have performace issues in the first code example? I doing there one big query to the database, and then I´m doing the query in the list of objects (which I think will be faster). I´m pretty new to this ORM, and this listing will have to handle a lot of registries..

I somebody can give me some advice? I made pretty much a mess explaining, hope you can understand..

Comment: _I think this way might have a big performance issues_ - Don't think, measure. Start by looking at the actual SQL that is generated. I would expect this to work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lista_cheques = db.Cheque.Include("Operacion").Include("Cliente").Where(x => x.fecha_deposito == fecha).ToList();
lista_cheques = lista_cheques.Where(x => x.banco.id_banco = banco).ToList();
lista_cheques = lista_cheques.Where(x => x.Operacion.Cliente.id_cliente = id_cliente).ToList();
```

Nearly perfect. Kill all those ToList and it is good.

The ToList means SQL is evaluated, so if all 3 flters trigger, 2 and 3 are evaluated in memory.

Kick the ToList away, and the different Where clauses get combined on the database.

Standard LINQ 101. Works like a charm and is always nice to see.

Then add as LAST line:

lista_cheques = lista_cheques.ToList ();

Comment: Right. I hadn't seen the `ToList()`s, too lazy to scroll.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, if I don´t write that ToList() at the end, SQL is still evaluating the query? I didn´t know that. The problem is that lista_cheques is a list. I will have to create a new variable to store the query. Right?

Comment: Yes, but you materialize the list AT THE END. FIRST you put together all where conditions, THEN in the last step you add "ToList". ToList foroces the sql execution, then every additional where happsens client side.